# Unable to connect to firebaseio.com

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire2

OK, this may not be the right place to post this, but I am exhausted on ideas.

I have an Ionic2 app with AngularFire2.  I can not connect to firebaseio.com from the mobile device.

It is likely a whitelist issue, but damned if I can find it. I have

```
<allow-intent href="https://*.firebaseio.com/*" />
```

everything woks fine in an emulator, localhost, just not on the physical device. I connected to the app running remote device with chrome-tools and did see that I am not connecting to the firebaseio.com server. I see

> Failed to load resource appname.firebaseio.com/.lp?start=t&ser=94215074&cb=12&v=5
>
> Failed to load resource appname.firebaseio.com/.lp?start=t&ser=94215074&cb=12&v=5

The status is (failed), not 404, not 500, just (failed).

I have updated everything. Firebase 2.7.8, Ionic-cli 2.2.3, angular 4.0.0, angularfire2 4.0.0-rc0 still same errors.

I have added the following the following cordova plugins, but nothing seems to help.

```
cordova-plugin-buildinfo 
cordova-universal-links-plugin 
cordova-plugin-browsertab 
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to change https://.firebaseio.com/ to https://*.firebaseio.com/* ? (missing *s)

Per the cordova [docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/):

> Wildcards are allowed for the protocol, as a prefix
>        to the host, or as a suffix to the path

Example:
`<allow-intent href="*://*.example.com/*" />`

Answer (score 1):

You currently have `.firebaseio.com` (emphasis on the `.` before `firebaseio`).  Usually you'll need to do something like `https://*.firebaseio.com`

Answer (score 0):

The platforms were corrupt.  I removed and added the android platform and that resolved the issue.